# String's split method shows undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to get all characters starting from = inside url:

```
let url = this.$route.query.item
      console.log(typeof(url)) // outputs string

     let status = url => url.split('=')[1]
```

it shows split as undefined. What is the problem and how can be it fixed?

Comment: What does url look like?

Comment: Your function parameter named `url` shadows the `let url` variable. So how is `status`  being called?

Comment: [Should work just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/6cewux2n/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
let url = "foo=bar";
console.log(typeof (url)) // outputs string

let status = url => url.split('=')[1]

console.log(status(url));// "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `this.$route.query.item` does not contain `=` character. if you are looking for current url try this may be

```
let url = this.$router.currentRoute;
console.log(url); // check if this is the url you expect
let status = 'url does not contain = char';
if(url.includes('='){
   status = url.split('=')[1];
}
console.log(status);
```

note: if you actually need to split `this.$route.query.item`, console log it and check if it contains `=` or perhaps add a check for it.